# Rails remote form not triggering ajax:success handler

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

Here's my view for the form:

```
#popupBox
  %h1 Change Password
  %p Update password for user: #{@user.email}.
  #formHolder
    = simple_form_for @user, url: update_password_user_path, html: { class: 'remote-form' }, remote: true do |f|
      = f.input :password, required: true

      = f.button :submit, 'Update Password'
```

Here's the controller code:

```
def update_password
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update(update_password_params)
    render layout: false # This shows a nice "Completed" message for the user.
  else
    render action: 'edit_password', layout: false
  end
end
```

And my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("form.remote-form").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    console.log("Working")
    $("form.remote-form").append xhr.responseText
  ).on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    console.log("Not working")
    $("form.remote-form").append "<p>ERROR</p>"
```

When I submit the form, an AJAX post is fired (seen in my dev tools) yet neither of the console.log calls are fired.

How can I detect when the form is submitted via AJAX and place the result from the controller code inside the forms location in the dom?

Comment: you must try this `ajax:error` event to catch error, may be you will find some clue there.

Comment: @ParitoshPiplewar: Sorry I'm not sure why the pasted code got mangled. I updated the question with the **actual** code.

Answer (score 0):

Add json response in the contoller:

```
  def update_password
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(update_password_params)
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :updated }
      else
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: But I don't want to return JSON, I want to return HTML that will be then `append`'d to the html dom.

Comment: You can also append json to any input you want, but send less data for example: https://gist.github.com/itsNikolay/760e6116b5bbe2447f4b  wish it helps